# Sharding one tfreocrd file Or split the original input dataset?

Tags: sharding

My Question is my training data is stored as one `tf.record` file of  333G and one epoch takes 3 hour to finish training. So what is the best way to split my data in order to improve the speed or performance on input pipeline:

1. Split the original dataset ( which in in `CSV` file) into 10 splits then create 10 tfrecord files.
2. Split the created one tfrecord file into multiple files through `tf.Dasata.shard`.If this option is better, how I should deal with shared dataset within Keras. Should I create 10 iterate? ( one iterator per each shard)?. I mean , I will not be able to save like 10 tfrecords file like option one, I will have one tfrecord file, but I just can get one shard at a time.

Comment: This question seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519309/split-tfrecords-file-into-many-tfrecords-files